# Get values of callback function sql

Tags: javascript, sql

I have problem with this variables, I want to check if they are the same and if yes I want the whole function "overeni" return true, but the variables are undefined I tried almost everything.

```
function overeni(id,auth){
  var sqlid;
  var sqlauth; 
  var sql = "SELECT id FROM login WHERE auth = " + client.escape(auth);
  client.query(sql ,function(err,res){      
    console.log(res[0].id); 
    sqlid = res[0].id;
  });
  var sql = "SELECT auth FROM login WHERE id = " + client.escape(id); 
  client.query(sql ,function(err,res){ 
    console.log(res[0].auth);
    sqlauth = res[0].auth;
  }); 
  if(id == sqlid && auth == sqlauth){
  return true;
  }
  else{
  return false;
  }    
}
```

Comment: It's because the `client.query()` calls are async, meaning that your if/else clause will be run before the two `.query()` calls are finished.

Comment: ah, is there any way how to manage this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways

1) use callbacks instead of return

```
function overeni(id,auth, callback){
....
client.query(sql ,function(err,res){      
    .....
    if (sqlid  && sqlauth) {callback(sqlid, sqlauth);}
```

});

2) or use some deferred library (like jquery/when/Q etc)